# Learning Web Design as a Form Designer

Tags: asp.net, web

I am trying to learn ASP.NET (C#) and the biggest struggle I am having is the design aspects of it. I have primarily been a windows form designer. All of the projects I have worked on have used windows forms and it was much more intuitive and cleaner to design in than HTML/CSS. I am trying to learn how to design web pages, but it seems all "design" needs to be done in CSS. How do you design something you don't see and just use pixels and references to other objects? I don't see how you design anything that way.

What is the best way for me to be able to effectively design for websites using CSS and ASP.NET coming from a more visual approach of windows forms? I have read 3 books on ASP.NET and it makes sense but all of the design is done is source views and CSS sheets. Is there another method or approach I should be aware of? I am using VS 2015 BTW as my IDE.

Please and thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS and HTML are the building blocks of the Web. Like you, I used to struggle moving from the Drag and Drop world of VS 2003 after initially starting out with just Netscape and Notepad in college. Drag and Drop, like Web Forms, is an unhealthy layer of abstraction in that it removes us from a true understanding of how the Web works.

Just accept that this is the nature of things and stop fighting it. Back in the days of VS 2003, our team would set up VS so as to never default to the designer panel when starting or opening projects. Besides, the tool was totally undependable and created a tangled Frontpage-style mess of so-called HTML.

Make the switch to pure, semantic markup and CSS. Download a good template from a site like [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/search?q=%22Bootstrap%203%22) (I usually search using "Bootstrap 3") to learn from. Study HTML5, CSS3 and RWD (Responsive Web Design) and let yourself have some fun. Yes, it really CAN be fun.

Work by switching from your IDE to the browser and back again.

Comment: Thanks. I did not intend to fight it but rather learn how to adjust my thinking and style along it. My main issue seems to be CSS and just having to do things manually without seeing it which makes design very difficult for me. Though, I found out that I don't have to use responsive design in my projects...so that frees up a lot of options for me to use. Thanks again.